# R read.table() does not include first column?

Tags: r

I try to read using `read.table()` a .txt file that looks like this:

```
       T1        A4        G7        G9       A9   
pat1     0     2     1     2     0
pat2     0     2     0     0     0
pat3     1     1     0     2     0
pat4     0     0     2     2     0
pat5     2     2     2     2     0
pat6     0     1     2     0     0
pat7     0     1     1     1     1
pat8     1     0     0     2     1
pat9     1     2     1     2     2
.
.
.
```

Here is how I read it:

```
data_file <- read.table(data_file_path, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = "", dec = ".")
```

But when I inspect it, it looks like this:

```
str(data_file)

## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ T1: int  0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 1 2 ...
##  $ A4: int  2 2 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 ...
##  $ G7: int  1 0 0 2 2 2 1 0 1 2 ...
##  $ G9: int  2 0 2 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 ...
##  $ A9: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 ...
```

Why does it not include the first column? I do not understand this?

Comment: Please check `rownames(data_file)` and use `data_file$Var <- rownames(data_file)` to assign them as variable

Comment: @Duck Thank you for comment. `rownames()` does print out the names, and using `data_file$Var <- rownames(data_file)` adds them as last variable. How come it didnt read those directly to the file? (I am new to R). Could you explain, please, if you have time?

Comment: For sure, it is because of the nature of the function. Let me add a solution explaining all details.

Comment: Please do, and thank you @Duck

Comment: I have added some light explanation, let me know if that was clear for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and belongs to some of the classic loading data functions in `R`. The function `read.table()` loads a `.txt` file. Now, some `.txt` files use to include an additional first unnamed column (empty header). Sometimes we think of it as an additional variable, but the function `read.table()` understands it as the rownames of data.

What is rownames? It is an unique value used by `R` to index all rows across a dataframe. When data do not contain that index from the reading source, an automatic index is created, starting from 1 to the number of rows.

If a function finds an unnamed column, it will take it as rownames. That is why when you loaded your data, you could not see that "variable". It will be in the data to track the order of rows, but you can assign them as a variable. With a little example, it will be clearer. I will be using `iris` dataset. First, I will create some rownames over the data and I will save as `.txt`:

```
#Rownames
rownames(iris)<-paste0(iris$Species,1:150)
#Export
write.table(iris,file='iris.txt',sep='\t')
```

Now, I will load it:

```
#Load
e1 <- read.table('iris.txt',sep='\t')
```

Checking data, we have:

```
str(e1)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

No pattern of my created rownames, but I can store them as a new variable:

```
#Var
e1$Var <- rownames(e1)
```

How data will look now:

[image]

Now, see how you have the index for rows, and the new variable. Sometimes can be troublesome, but if the first column in your data is unnamed, it will be taken as rownames. You can save it as a new variable and then remove the rownames using:

```
#Remove
rownames(e1)<-NULL
```

Data will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Duck, very helpful post. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Carlton Great! Also upvoted your question as it is a good memory from classic R!